# Show a multi-variable function is not continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Consider the function $f : R^2 → R$ given by
>
> $$
> f(x, y) =
> \begin{cases}
> \begin{matrix}
> \frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2} & \mathrm{if}\ (x, y) \ne(0, 0)\\
> 0 & \mathrm{if}\ (x, y) = (0, 0) \\
> \end{matrix}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> Show that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

**Solution:**

Assume some arbitrary values, $x_k=\left(\frac{1}{k~},0\right)$ and $y_k=\left(\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k}\right)$.

Substituting $x_k$ into our function

$$\lim_{k\to0}f\left(\frac{1}{k},0\right)=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{k}\cdot0}{\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^4+0}$$

We can see that

$$\lim_{k\to0}f\left(\frac{1}{k},0\right)=0$$

Substituting $y_k$ into our function

$$\lim_{k\to0}f\left(\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k}\right)=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{1}{k}}{\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^4+\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^2}\ne0$$

Hence the function $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$

**Is my solution correct? How can I improve it?**

Comment: $$\frac{\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{1}{k}}{\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^4+\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^2}=\frac{k^2}{1+k^2}\to 0$$ as $k\to 0$. Thus this limit does not disprove continuity. (More generally, you can check that $f(x,ax)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ for any $a$. So the failure of $f(x,y)$ to be continuous cannot be shown by approaching the origin along some straight line.)

Comment: What method would you use?

Comment: @james15c The reason the limit is $0$ along any straight line is that $f(x,ax) = ax^3/(x^4 + a^2 x^2) = ax/(x^2 + a^2)$ has a constant term in the denominator, forcing the limit as $x \to 0$ to be $0$. So: how can you choose a different path to take so that the denominator has no constant term after simplification?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I' not sure, what would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: What happens with $f(t,t^2)$ as $t\to 0$?

Comment: We find an answer $\frac{1}{2}$ and it is not continuous, thank you. Is there any cases where a different method is required?